# Combine two arrays in nested foreach loop php

Tags: php

I have two arrays order1 and order2. I want to get information from line items and note attributes. I am finding sku from line items and inserting in new array pre_purchased_data
and find source and customer from note attributes. No matter from which order i found source and customer  i want to insert both values in pre_purchased_data array.

```
order1 = Array
(
    [note_attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => SOURCE
                    [value] => t2aV9tJKnB
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => PAYMENTINTENT
                    [value] => I5sUmNEiE4PG0g
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => PAYMENTMETHOD
                    [value] => I5sUmNmAqwKrtO
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [name] => CUSTOMER
                    [value] => t2aV9tJKnK
                )

        )

    [line_items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => 104022/A
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => 104034/A
                )

        )

)

order2 = Array
(
    [note_attributes] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => SOURCE
                    [value] => 
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => MENTINTENT
                    [value] => pi_1Gp5Xq43wq
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => NTMETHOD
                    [value] => pm_1Gp5ZV43wqO
                )

        )

    [line_items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => 104000/E
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => 104000/A
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => YEAR-PLAN
                )

        )

)
```

My PHP CODE

```
         foreach ($orders as $order) {
            $pre_purchased_data = array();
            if (isset($order_array['line_items']) && !empty($order_array['line_items'])) {
                foreach ($order_array['line_items'] as $items) {
                    if (isset($items['sku']) && $items['sku'] == MONTH-PLAN) {
                        $pre_purchased_data['preselect_plan_type'] = 'SM';
                        break;
                    } elseif (isset($items['sku']) && $items['sku'] == 'YEAR-PLAN') {
                        $pre_purchased_data['preselect_plan_type'] = 'SY';
                        break;
                    } elseif (isset($items['sku']) && $items['sku'] == CM-PLAN/Y) {
                        $pre_purchased_data['preselect_plan_type'] = 'CM';
                        break;
                    } elseif (isset($items['sku']) && $items['sku'] == CY-PLAN/Y) {
                        $pre_purchased_data['preselect_plan_type'] = 'CY';
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (isset($order_array['note_attributes']) && !empty($order_array['note_attributes'])) {
                foreach ($order_array['note_attributes'] as $note_attributes) {
                    if (isset($note_attributes['name']) && $note_attributes['name'] == 'SOURCE')
                        $pre_purchased_data['stripe_details']['stripe_source_id'] = ($note_attributes['value']) ? $note_attributes['value'] : '';
                    else if (isset($note_attributes['name']) && $note_attributes['name'] == 'CUSTOMER')
                        $pre_purchased_data['stripe_details']['stripe_customer_id'] = ($note_attributes['value']) ? $note_attributes['value'] : '';
                }
            }
        }

        print_r($pre_purchased_data);
```

ACTUAL RESULT

```
Array
(
    [preselect_plan_type] => SY
    [stripe_details] => Array
        (
            [stripe_source_id] => 
        )

)
```

EXPECTED RESULT

```
Array
(
    [preselect_plan_type] => SY
    [stripe_details] => Array
        (
            [stripe_source_id] => t2aV9tJKnB
            [stripe_customer_id] => t2aV9tJKnK
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
    $pre_purchased_data = [];
    foreach ($orders as $order) {
        if (isset($order['line_item']) && !empty($order['line_item'])) {
            foreach ($order['line_item'] as $item) {
                if (isset($item['sku']) && $item['sku'] == 'MONTH-PLAN') {
                    $pre_purchased_data['preselect_plan_type'] = 'SM';
                    break;
                } elseif (isset($item['sku']) && $item['sku'] == 'YEAR-PLAN') {
                    $pre_purchased_data['preselect_plan_type'] = 'SY';
                    break;
                } elseif (isset($item['sku']) && $item['sku'] == 'CM-PLAN/Y') {
                    $pre_purchased_data['preselect_plan_type'] = 'CM';
                    break;
                } elseif (isset($item['sku']) && $item['sku'] == 'CY-PLAN/Y') {
                    $pre_purchased_data['preselect_plan_type'] = 'CY';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (isset($order['note_attributes']) && !empty($order['note_attributes'])) {
            foreach ($order['note_attributes'] as $note_attributes) {
                if (isset($note_attributes['name']) && $note_attributes['name'] == 'SOURCE' && $note_attributes['value']) {
                    $pre_purchased_data['stripe_details']['stripe_source_id'] = $note_attributes['value'];
                } elseif (isset($note_attributes['name']) && $note_attributes['name'] == 'CUSTOMER' && $note_attributes['value']) {
                    $pre_purchased_data['stripe_details']['stripe_customer_id'] = $note_attributes['value'];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    print_r($pre_purchased_data);
```